# c++ destructor for a binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, destructor

When i run the destructor i get a run failed and i am not sure why here is my tree header

```
class ExpressionTree {
private:
    ExpressionNode* root;
public:
    ExpressionTree() :
    hashmap(100000),
    root(NULL) {
    };
    virtual ~ExpressionTree(){
        helper(root);
    }

    void helper(ExpressionNode *node) {
        if ( !node ) {
            return;
        } else {
            helper( node->getLeft( ) );
            helper( node->getRight( ) );
            delete node;
        }
    }
};
```

and my node header

```
class ExpressionNode {
private:
    ExpressionNode* left;
    ExpressionNode* right;
    string data;
public:
    virtual ~ExpressionNode(){
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }
};
```

Now everything works fine if in the ExpressionTree class i only destroy the root but i believe i am leaking memory that way. Is that in fact the right way or is there something wrong with my recursive destruction.

Comment: You are deleting memory twice. Don't do that! And initialize your pointers to `nullptr`, otherwise you will try to delete random memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ExpressionNode` destructor adequately cleans up it's memory which because it destroys it's children which adequately clean up their memory and so on. What you are doing right now is double-freeing the nodes; once by `helper()` and once by the destructors themselves. All you need to do is destroy the root node

```
virtual ~ExpressionTree(){
    delete root;
}
```

all the children nodes will be deleted through the destructors.